# How can i overcome 1MB Restriction of /dev/mem

Tags: linux, fedora, memory-management

I am trying to access to physical memory through accessing to /dev/mem device in fedora, and only i could access to first 1MB of /dev/mem. i tried to set strict_devmem=0 in /etc/default/grub file but it did not solve problem. could anyone please describe me how can i access to all of physical memory through /dev/mem?

Answer (score 2):

Dumping memory on Linux might be different among different distributions or
kernel version.
The previously used memory device (`/dev/mem`) became over time more and more
restricted in order to avoid a malicious process directly accessing kernel memory.
The kernel option `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` was introduced for that in kernel version
2.6 and later. So you'll need to use a Linux kernel module in order to acquire memory.

Below is some information I have compiled on the subject.

See GitHub project [fmem](https://github.com/NateBrune/fmem):

> This module creates **/dev/fmem** device,
>   that can be used for dumping physical memory,
>   without limits of `/dev/mem` (1MB/1GB, depending on distribution)

Another alternative is
[LiME](https://github.com/504ensicslabs/lime):

> A Loadable Kernel Module (LKM) which allows for volatile memory acquisition from Linux and Linux-based devices, such as Android. This makes LiME unique as it is the first tool that allows for full memory captures on Android devices. It also minimizes its interaction between user and kernel space processes during acquisition, which allows it to produce memory captures that are more forensically sound than those of other tools designed for Linux memory acquisition.

Lime supports more recent versions of the Linux Kernel and the technique to
expose and acquire memory is less intrusive.

Comment: thanks. By "So you'll need to use a Linux kernel module in order to acquire memory" you meaning that i can read/write to /dev/mem from an kernel module without recompiling kernel? right?

Comment: No, modifying the kernel is too difficult, but you can add other mechanisms. The first above adds `/dev/fmem` which is the same as `/dev/mem` but without the 1MB restriction. The second one adds a way to copy memory using utilities.